# How can I make this script fit the prompt below? Perl

Tags: perl, package, subroutine

Write a perl script that defines a variable with 1 or more packages names and then calls a subroutine which contains system commands to update and upgrade the OS, and then installs the packages defined in the pre-defined variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $x= "Program";

sub Install {
system ("sudo apt-update");
system ("sudo apt-upgrade");
system ("sudo apt-install $x");
}
install();
```

Comment: Your question sounds like some kind of assignment. Well such kind of task would be more appropriate to perform in shell. The advantage is that shell installed in any Unix/Linux OS, but perl very often requires an installation on it's own.

Comment: Performing system calls without input checking is very dangerous. Try to find a module that does the job, if you feel you have to do it this way. (Preferably: Don't) Also, subroutine names are case specific.

Comment: For example, what if someone would enter `"'' ; rm -rf /"` as input to your script?

Comment: Just a note for the sake of precision: Your sample has a typo error: the subroutine call should be `Install()`.

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet adds prompt and waits for user input of package name

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter package name: ";

my $pkg = <>;

sub Install {
   system ('sudo', 'apt-update');
   system ('sudo', 'apt-upgrade');
   system ('sudo', 'apt-install', $pkg);
}

install();

exit 0;
```

Such tasks should be performed from `root` account which would not require `sudo` (but `root` should be very careful when types any command, verify typed command before pressing `Enter`).

Shell would be more suitable to perform such task(s) as perl very often is not installed due security concern.

For example *bash* script would look like following

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install $1
```

Reference: [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system)